# setInterval function is running in other components also in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, setinterval

I am new to Angular(6). I am using `setInterval` function in a component. It is working but when I navigate to another route, `setInterval` continues to execute. Please help me to identify the reason.

```
//Calling it in ngOnit()
autosavedraftsolution() {
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);
        if (this.solutionTitleValid) {
          this.savedraftsolution();
        }
      }, this.autoSaveInterval);
    }

//savedraftsolution()
  savedraftsolution() {
    console.log("saving..");

    this.connectService.saveDraftSolution({
      Title: this.draftSolutionForm.get('Title').value,
      Product: this.draftSolutionForm.get('Product').value
    } as Draftsolution).subscribe(draftsol => {
      console.log("saved");

    });
  }
```

It keeps on showing me "saving.." and "saved" message in console.

Comment: Does anything ever try to stop the interval? If not, then it's doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Pointy oops...I'm sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `clearInterval` to stop it when your component unmounts:

```
this.intervalId = setInterval(...);
```

When your component is [unmounting](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy):

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dominic is right. You have to clear the interval when the component is destroyed. You can make something like this

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.saveInterval = setInterval(() => {}, 1000)
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    clearInterval(this.saveInterval)
}
```

Make sure that your component implements OnInit and OnDestroy.